# How to NOT execute a command using GNU readline in vi mode on linux

Tags: bash, gnu, readline

I am used to using readline's vi mode for bash and found [this](https://github.com/pkrumins/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/blob/master/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt). My question is, from vi mode, having entered some characters, I want to do one of the following:

1. exit vi mode and discard the command[s] and leave bash at the prompt.  I would have thought :q or :q! would do it. I could delete the contents of the buffer and exit I guess but was thinking there was something more elegant.
2. exit vi mode and leave the the contents of the buffer on the bash command line without executing it.

Note, I did not see the answer in man 3 readline for GNU Readline 8.1

Comment: Do you mean something like: `0i#<esc><ret>`?  `0` -> Move to line start  'i#<esc>` -> Insert a hash to make it a comment. `<ret>` -> execute the comment.

Comment: Ill take that as the easiest  thx

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what you meant, so I'll answer two questions.

**While editing a command in `vim`, how do I leave `vim` without exiting the command?**

If the editor returns a nonzero status code, bash will not execute the command. To do this in vim: `<esc>:cq<ret>`.

**In bash `vi` editing mode, how do I leave a command in my history without executing it?**

From normal mode: `#`.

From insert mode: `<esc>#`.